# Spring Boot Security enabled only to selected HttpRequest Methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement some custom security on Spring Boot using Spring Security package.

Currently every request requires authentication.

I would like to allow all non authenticated requests made with HttpHeader.OPTIONS or HEAD to not require any sort of authentication.

Here is my security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(
                    new ManagementEndpointAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()),
                    BasicAuthenticationFilter.class
            );

    http.csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.HEAD, "/api/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers((String[]) ACTUATOR_ENDPOINTS.toArray()).hasAuthority(role).anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .anonymous().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint());

}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(managementUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider())
        .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider managementUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new ManagementUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new TokenAuthenticationProvider(tokenService, userService, token);
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint() {
    return (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I may not expressed myself correctly, currently every request needs to be authenticated. That line isn't working as expected.

Comment: I have no clue on what you are trying to achieve not from your question nor from. your configuration.

Comment: I want to enable authentication to all enpoints, except when the HTTPMethod is Options or Head.

Comment: Then just configure that. First configure the exceptions and for the remainder add `anyRequest.authenticated()`. You need just 3 lines of configuration in the correct order.

Comment: But that would enable authentication in all endpoints and all request methods, that's not what i'm looking to. I've edited the question , tell me if my purpose is more clear to you.

Comment: Read, again read. First configure the 2 exceptions (for OPTIONS and HEAD) THEN add `anyRequest.authenticated()` currently you first do `anyRequest.authenticated()` and as that is first everything requires authentication and basically renders all your other ant matchers useless.

Comment: I've updated the question code block, is this compliant with what you mentioned ?

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. The `.anyRequest().authenticated()` should always be the last one currently it is stil in between other ant matchers.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue, it was missing the .cors() method.

So my current configuration is:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {



    http.csrf().disable()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.HEAD, "/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers((String[]) ACTUATOR_ENDPOINTS.toArray()).hasAuthority(role).anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint());


    http.addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(
                new ManagementEndpointAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()),
                BasicAuthenticationFilter.class
        );

}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(managementUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider())
        .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
    configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider managementUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new ManagementUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new TokenAuthenticationProvider(tokenService, userService, token);
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint() {
    return (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```